# CSS gradients not applied to the last page

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, deployment, css-gradients

So I created a portfolio website using React. I applied CSS gradient animations to the body of the index.html file. I have totally 5 pages. The CSS gradient do work in the first four pages. But when I go to the last page which is my projects page the gradient does not apply, it shows white background with my components,but if you fiddle around the website for sometime then the CSS gradient is being applied to the last page.

index.html

````
<body>
   <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->

    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1352a67a6e.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>

index.css

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  color: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(
    -45deg,
    #b3ffab,
    #12fff7,
    #e6dada,
    #ddd6f3,
    #faaca8,
    #23d5ab,
    #23a6d5
  );
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  position: relative;
  animation: change 10s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes change {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 50%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0 50%;
  }
}

projects.js

class Projects extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="projects">
        <h1 className="animated slideInDown">My Projects</h1>
        <div className="grid">
          <div className="animated slideInLeft row no-gutters row1">
            <div className="col no-gutters">
              <ProjectsComponent
                title="Burger Builder"
                text="Created a Web application using React and Redux. A web application where one can create an account and build burgers and order them. Technologies used are React router, Thunk, Axios, Jest/Enzyme, WebPack, Bable & Firebase."
                src={bb}
                link="https://burger-builder-application.firebaseapp.com/"
              />
            </div>
9 sections like the above


projects.css

.projects {
  margin-left: 7em;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  overflow: auto;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

.grid {
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}```
````

Comment: Can you host the site on codesandbox? It would be better to identify the problem there.

Comment: The problem is there are many files to upload and many dependencies. You can check the site here https://portfolio-2b745.firebaseapp.com/. Another thing that I found is if I go to the projects page from the navbar then the styling is getting applied. But when I go to projecst page from the buttons provided then it shows a blank page.

Comment: Actually, never mind, I found why it wasn't applying styles. It was because of react router. I placed a backslash at the end of the page, so that page didn't exist, but because of react router the content was showing up.